# reduceRegion works but reduceRegions returns null values for all reducer

Tags: google-earth-engine, null, reducers, mean, reduceregion

When using ee.reduceRegions() I try to estimate the mean values of copernicus landcover values within all features in a feature collection I get 'null' as a result for all reducers I have tried  (mean, min, first, etc).  However when I use ee.reduceRegion() (notice no 's') I get a result for the mean value for the entire feature collection. How do I get mean values for each feature?  Here is a reproducible example:

```
// Load input imagery: Copernicus land cover.
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019');

print(image)
// Load a FeatureCollection of counties in Maine.
var maineCounties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('STATEFP', '23'));
print(maineCounties)

var clip = image.clip(maineCounties);
Map.addLayer(clip, {}, "Tree Cover");

// Add reducer output to the Features in the collection.
var maineMeansFeatures = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: maineCounties,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
});

// Print the first feature, to illustrate the result.
print(ee.Feature(maineMeansFeatures.first()).select(image.bandNames()));


// Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
var meanDictionary = image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: maineCounties.geometry(),
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print(meanDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a CRS seems to solve the issue:

```js
var maineMeansFeatures = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: maineCounties,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  crs: "EPSG:5070",
});

print(maineMeansFeatures.aggregate_count_distinct("tree-coverfraction")); // 16
```

I'm not sure why that's necessary with `reduceRegions` but not `reduceRegion`. Even weirder, it looks like you can also solve the issue by limiting the size of `maineCounties` to its current size, which *should* have no effect:

```js
var maineMeansFeatures = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: maineCounties.limit(maineCounties.size()),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
});

print(maineMeansFeatures.aggregate_count_distinct("tree-coverfraction")); // 16
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but you could consider opening a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:184406).

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a bug where the system essentially thinks the collection is empty for some purposes (filter propagation).

The workaround is, indeed, to `.limit()` the collection with some large number.  (Anything that causes the collection to be completely manifested in memory works; that's the easiest one).